# (Enderton set theory) Hartog's theorem and cardinal numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, cardinals

Assume that A is a set and define (as in Hartogs' theorem) $\alpha$ to be the set of ordinals dominated by A. Show that (i) $\alpha$  is a cardinal number, (ii) card A < $\alpha$ , and (iii) $\alpha$  is the least cardinal greater than card A.

This question is from Enderton textbook. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: I have tried the following to think about (i), (ii) and (iii), although I don't think it's a meaningful progress.
(i) $\alpha$ has to be an initial ordinal number for it to be a cardinal number. How do we show if $\alpha$ is an initial ordinal number?
(ii) $\alpha$ is equinumerous to card($\alpha$). Since $\alpha$ is the set of ordinals dominated by A, $card (\alpha)\leq card A$.

I feel like this problem shouldn't be hard, but I'm stuck for some reason. I would appreciate any help on this problem and any suggestion as to how I could improve on thinking about those problems. (I don't think my understanding of axiom of choice is thorough - how would you advise me to study the axiom of choice?)

Comment: What have you tried? Please edit your attempts into the problem.

Comment: Just edited, although I do not think it's a meaningful progress. Thank you for the comment!

Comment: The cardinality of $\alpha$ is not $\leq$ the cardinality of $A$. I'd suggest properly studying the material here: to be honest, it seems like you have quite a few gaps in your understanding of ordinals and set theory. For a kind introduction to the material (although a bit tedious at times), Halmos's set theory should be fine.

Comment: Well.. maybe not the ordinals bc I just started studying them, but I think I do have an understanding of a set dominating another set. Do you mind kindly explaining how card(alpha)>card(A) when A is the set dominating alpha?

Comment: $A$ doesn't dominate $\alpha$. $A$ dominates every element of $\alpha$. If $A$ dominated $\alpha$, $\alpha\in\alpha$, which is a violation of the axiom of regularity.

Comment: @DonThousand: If $\alpha\in\alpha$, that would violate the fact that ordinals are well-orders long before it violates the axiom of regularity.

Comment: Ok, I probably misread the question because I was solving this in the middle of the night and that's also why i was really confused. In order to show that $\alpha$ is a cardinal, we'd show card($\alpha$) = $\alpha$. Do you have any hints to show this?

Comment: Easier. Show that it does not inject into any of its elements. Which is the actual definition of a cardinal.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Do we show this by saying if it does inject into an element of itself, alpha also injects into A because of the composition of functions, and then it means alpha is an element of itself?

Comment: Again, slightly easier. You know that such ordinal $\alpha$ exists, and you're looking at the smallest one. In particular, any smaller ordinal injects into $A$, but if $\alpha$ injects into some $\beta<\alpha$, then by definition $\beta$ injects into $A$, and as you suggest by composing the two injections $\alpha$ would also inject into $A$, but we assumed that it doesn't.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you very much! I'm also not sure how I can show (iii), where   is the least cardinal greater than card A. I am particularly not sure because A is not specified an ordinal, so UA is not the least upper bound. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Again, any ordinal smaller than $\alpha$ injects into $A$, so the cardinality of any ordinal smaller than $\alpha$ is $\leq|A|$. This is really just beating the same dead horse...

Answer (score 1):

$(i)$ If $\beta<\alpha$, then $\beta$ is dominated by $A$, and so $\beta$ is not equinumerous to $\alpha$. It follows that $\text{card }\alpha=\alpha$, i.e. $\alpha$ is a cardinal.

$(ii)$ If $\alpha\leq \text{card } A$, then  $\text{card } \alpha\leq \text{card } A$, and so $\alpha$ would be dominated by $A$. This contradicts the definition of $\alpha$. Hence $\text{card } A < \alpha$.

$(iii)$ If $\beta$ is a cardinal with $\text{card } A < \beta$, then  $\text{card } A < \text{card } \beta$, i.e. $\text{card } \beta\leq \text{card } A $ is false. It follows that $\beta$ is not dominated by $A$. Hence $\alpha\leq \beta$ by definition of $\alpha$.